# Запуск по времени

Tags: java

Мне нужно, чтобы программа запускалась в определенные дни в определенное время. Как можно такое сделать средставим `java` ?

Comment: Вы это хотите реализовать с помощью java или с помощью ОС? Если с помощью java, программа должна быть у вас запущена

Comment: c java возможно только запустить некоторый поток, выполняющий определенное действие. Если вы хотите запускать именно программу то посмотрите в сторону cron (для линукс) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron или что то подобное

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Не хочу по cron'у, хочу средствами java.

Comment: @faoxis средствами java  можно только до перезагрузки компьютера. запускать процесс и ждать нужной времени. тогда процесс запускает либо пользователь, либо планировщик,  в любом случае нужны действия из вне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) - она позволяет создавать расписание запуска в определенные дни недели/месяца и тому подобное. Например вот так:

1) Создаем задачу, которую будем запускать по расписанию:

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job
{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
    //запускаемая по расписанию задача

    }
}
```

2) Создаем расписание запуска и связываем задачу и расписание в планировщике:

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                        .newJob(QuartzJob.class)
                        .withIdentity("QuartzJob", "group1")
                        .build();

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                        .newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("QuartzTrigger", "group1")
                        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
.cronSchedule("0 0 9-18/1 ? * MON,TUE,WED"))
                        .build();


SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
sched.start();
sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
```

В данном примере задача запускается каждый час в 0 секунд и 0 минут в период с 9 до 18 часов каждый понедельник, вторник и среду. Подробнее про конфигурацию планировщика можно прочитать в документации [ссылка №1](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) и [ссылка №2](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html).

Comment: Не могли бы вы ответить на этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586196/Запуск-задач-в-разное-время-с-помощью-quartz ?