# Запуск задач в разное время с помощью Quartz

Tags: java

Хочу сделать так, что мой код запускался по двум временным показателям. Вот так не работает:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SchedulerException {



    JobDetail job = JobBuilder
            .newJob(QuartzJob.class)
            .withIdentity("QuartzJob", "group1")
            .build();

    Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                    .cronSchedule("0 13 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI")
                    .cronSchedule("0 14 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU"))
            .build();


    SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
    sched.start();
    sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger1);
}
```

Как сделать правильно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На одно задание можно поставить несколько триггеров, как показано на примере ниже. При этом само задание должно сохраняться в планировщике, даже если оно не связано ни с одним триггером, за это отвечает метод `storeDurably`. Связку между триггером и заданием указываем в триггере с помощью метода `forJob`.

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                .newJob(QuartzJob.class)
                .withIdentity("QuartzJob", "group1")
                .storeDurably()
                .build();

Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                        .cronSchedule("0 13 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI"))
                .forJob(job)
                .build();
Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger2", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                        .cronSchedule("0 14 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU"))
                .forJob(job)
                .build();

SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
        sched.start();

sched.addJob(job, true);
sched.scheduleJob(trigger1);
sched.scheduleJob(trigger2);
```